# Laravel validating that key in array is in an array of given strings

Tags: laravel, validation

I'm building an API that takes in an array of 'additional_data' but I want some control over the fields that can be passed in.

Take the following JSON:

```
{
    "name": "Joe Bloggs",
    "additional_data": {
        "type": "example",
        "other_type": "example"
    }
}
```

My current validation attempt:

```
return [
    'name' => ['required'],
    'additional_data.*' => ['sometimes', Rule::in(['type'])]
];
```

This always fails validation, what I'm looking for is to validate the key of the array so I can make sure the keys passed in are part of a 'whitelist'.

Answer (score 0):

What you do now is you try to validate content of `additional_data.type` and `additional_data.other_type`.

You can do this by adding a custom validator. For example

```
Validator::extend('check_additional_data_keys', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
    return is_array($value) && array_diff(array_keys($value), ['type', 'other_type']) === 0);
});
```

and use it inside your current rules

```
return [
    'name' => ['required'],
    'additional_data' => ['check_additional_data_keys'],
    'additional_data.*' => ['required', 'string'],
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just [specify your whitelist keys](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#validating-arrays) using the [`array`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-array) validation rule:

```php
return [
    'name' => 'required',
    'additional_data' => [
        'sometimes', 
        'array:type',
    ],
];
```

Comment: This has exposed the issue potentially, when returning the request 'additional_data' it's still and object. Will look at best way to handle API json request to convert to array.

Answer (score 0):

1- In case you want applay same validation on all arrays' keys you can use the following:

```
   return [
        'name' => 'required',
        'additional_data' => ['array', Rule::in(['type'])]
        ];
```

2- In case each key in the array needs different validation use the following:

```
   return [
        'name' => 'required',
        'additional_data' => 'array',
        'additional_data.ky1' => ['your validation here'],
        'additional_data.ky2' => ['your validation here'],
        ];
```